# can't disable multicast on ppp0 using ifconfig: SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted

Tags: networking, security, ifconfig, pppoe

I'm trying to permanently disable multicasting, peer-to-peer and allmulti on a ppp0e connectino. 
I have been following instructions on doing this using ifconfig but get an error:

When I type this following or similar:

```
     ifconfig ppp0 -allmulti
```

I get:

```
    SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
    Warning: Interface ppp0 still in ALLMULTI mode.
```

I tried a network restart

```
    sudo service networking restart
```

But get the same response. How can I do this or is there some other way. 
I'm on ubuntu v 16.04.